# Android SQLiteDatabase working with Emulator but not on Real Device

Tags: android, sqlite, emulation

Firstly, what works is: A simple application that contains a sqliteDatabase. I populate this in the main activity and when the other activity is called, it queries the database and returns a string array. I put this result into a spinner using 'new ArrayAdapter'.

I don't think the code matters in this case as it works on the emulator fine. The spinner is populated ok on the emulator but won't populate on the phone?

Maybe the database doesn't even get created on the phone?

Anyone know what could be the cause of the problem? Thanks!

Comment: cross check your database created path

Comment: Try logging in when you create a The database and run on phone then see what is the problem in Logcat

Comment: Try uninstalling the application from device, restart device and then install your application.

Comment: Thank you Sunil Kumar! Works now :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Your suspicion that the database isn't created might be a hint (is it likely you have been developing solely using the emulator and the database has been built in previous builds, whereas the current build doesn't create a new one when it doesn't yet exist ?).

Try logging whether the "onCreate"-method of the SQLiteDataBase class is fired when the class is instantiated. Try logging the SQL results for queries as they might indicate what is wrong (i.e. non-existing tables or column names, etc).